# Simple HTML / CSS box model confusion

Tags: html, css

Using this really simple html / css (http://jsfiddle.net/XXzTj/)

```
<div style="background-color:red;">
<div style="margin:12px; background:blue;">hello</div>
</div>
```

The margin is spaced 12px all round correctly, but I was expecting the red background of the parent element to be shown in the top and bottom 12px spaces, instead its just 'blank space'.

Am I going mad or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  --

```
<div style="background-color:red;height:auto;overflow:hidden;">
<div style="margin:12px; background:blue;">hello</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XXzTj/1/

Answer (score 1):

The child div is forcing the parent div to be rendered offset from its surroundings because you are using the margin property. Since the parent div has no content the browser has no reason to apply styling above or below the child div.

In order to honour the margin properties of the child div, however, which *does* have content, the parent div is rendered with its background either side of the content.

To have the browser render it in the way I imagine you expect, you would need to apply the `padding` style. Again, that's because the parent div has no content. Padding forces its styles to be rendered within the area because padding essentially acts like space that *content* would fill up.

Answer (score 1):

It's [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) in action. Either use `padding` for parent element instead of `margin` for child one, or create new context by setting `position: relative`, `overflow: auto/scroll/hidden`, or add generated content (`:before` and `:after` pseudoelements) with `display: block` to parent element to prevent margin collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure why that isnt working to be honest but this does work:

```
<div style="background-color:red; padding:12px;">
    <div style="background:blue;">hello</div>
</div>
```

​