# Div wrappers - odd behavior with margin-top when removing border and padding

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="WrapperInner">
        <div class="Content"></div>
    </div>
</div>


div.Wrapper 
{ 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid blue;  
    padding: 5px; 
}
div.WrapperInner 
{ 
    height: 150px; 
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 5px; 
}

div.Content 
{ 
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red; 
    margin-top: 30px; 
}
```

And it looks fine. However, if I remove the border and padding of `div.WrapperInner`, the `margin-top` of the content is affecting it as well:

```
div.WrapperInner
{
    height: 150px; 
    border-left: 2px solid green;
    border-right: 2px solid green;
    /* either of the following would fix the difference:
       padding: 1px;
       border: 2px solid green; */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9F3Jw/

[image]

What is causing this difference? Why would the border or the padding cause the inner wrapper to be pushed lower?

Comment: It's [collapsing margins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291436/simple-html-css-box-model-confusion/9300132#9300132).

Answer (score 2):

there is example

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/9F3Jw/2/

```
div.WrapperInnerOdd
{
    overflow:hidden;// add this
}
```

or http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/9F3Jw/4/

```
div.WrapperInnerOdd
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%
}
```